# Module not found: Can't resolve 'x' in 'y' from Package Registry

Tags: reactjs, npm, gitlab, yarn-v2

I recently created my very first package in my project's Package Registry through `GitLab`.

It was published correctly and I was even able to `yarn add ...` the package in question to another repo.

Checking the node_modules I can see the package present. However, when I run `import` I am told that the module was not found.

I assume I'm either `importing` badly or `exporting` badly (or maybe both)

My `package.json` of the file I am exporting from has the following:

```
{
  "name": "@thing/thing2",
  "version": "0.1.2",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "many packages"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "something"
  },
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

The component I am after lives in `src/thing1/file.jsx`
And I'm importing the file as:

```
import {stuff} from "@thing/thing2"
```

I'm sure there is documentation online for how to do this but I'm clearly searching for it wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add:

```
  "type": "module",
  "module": "./src/module-export.jsx",
```

to the package file.